# Reading registry value into properties

Tags: registry, windows-installer, orca, visual-studio-setup

Is it possible to make a MSI to read a registry value and put it into a property without using C# custom actions?

I could make it with custom actions but I know that some actions, such as looking for file or folder can be done within the MSI itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define a new search in the MSI package, using [AppSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RegLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tables.