# MSI Property Value get reset when uninstallation get interrupt or clicking cancel during uninstallation

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

If I save the Authkey in MSI property for eg : “AUTHKEY” , when I click on cancel or uninstallation get interrupt, the property value is reset to default.

Do we have other way other than MSI property to store a value. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer properties, like **AUTHKEY**, have a valid scope **only** while the installer package is running. When an installation is finished/canceled and started again all values are reset to their defaults.

To have a value persistent, i.e. use on maintenance the value set when the package was installed, you need to save it, usually in a registry value, and read it from there using a [registry search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058800/reading-registry-value-into-properties/19087373#19087373). The search should have the exact property name, so when it is executed is sets the property directly with the value found in the registry value.