# Maintaining previously created registry entries when installing a newer version of an msi

Tags: installation, registry, windows-installer

I need to maintain registry entries that were created by a previous version of a Visual Studio Installer (msi).

So, for example, if I have a product, with product name "Product 1" version 1.0.1 which creates a registry key `"HKCU\Software\Product 1"` and also creates a value in that registry of `"Username`" that is updated by the installed application.

Installed application persists the user's username to `"HKCU\Software\Product 1\Username"` and I need to now release a new version using *Visual Studio Installer* project and the new version has a version of 1.0.2.

If I set `"RemovePreviousVersion"` to `true` in the installer project, the registry key created by the previous version is removed and the stored username is removed require the user to re-enter the username.

How can I uninstall the previous version without removing the registry key and value `"HKCU\Software\Product 1\Username"`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to use the same username for the new version or also want to keep the old entries in the registry?

If you just want to read the username, so you don't ask the user to input it again, it is simple. I explained how in the following [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058800/reading-registry-value-into-properties/19087373#19087373).

To have the registries from the old version remain on the machine is a little bit tricky, and I do not recommend it. As from what I see you just want to re-use that value from the registry, because the new version will write back into the registry.

Comment: Yes I do want to keep the old values. That's the problem. If the new installer can read the old value and restore them AFTER the previous version has been uninstalled, that will work.

Comment: Yes it can read them, as exlained in the link from my answer. Then you just write it back in the registry from the new version installer.